# App rejected because of forcing registration - ebook store

Tags: ios, app-store

I developed an app for the company who sells professional e-books by their website. In order to keep the content in sync with web data, app enforce login/registration and without that doesn't provide any functionality.

This is the reason why it has been rejected for Review Guidelines **17.2 Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected**

My question is: is there a way to convince Apple to accept an app?

1. It is directed to the very specific proffessionals.
2. In the future the company want to add the possibility to sync books available on their website.
3. Also the books bought by in app purchase would be available on their website for the user account.

Isn't that enough reasons for Apple to accept this app? My client strongly want to have an account based app, the whole system was designed for that.

There is possibility to track user by udid but still it is not good solution because it is deprecated and Apple rejects apps using UDID for tracking reasons.

Does anyone have similar situation recently?

Comment: So user signs up to your App and when they purchase a book it will also show up in the website to..

Comment: It doesn't have that functionality right now, but it is planned in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You say:

> "app enforces login/registration and without that doesn't provide any
>   functionality."

Apple says:

> "Apps that require users to share personal information in order to
>   function will be rejected"

So the answer is kinda obvious.

> **The app should provide (at least) some basic functionality without sharing personal data.**

Maybe some book previews? 1 or 2 free books? App info? Why not apple's-bookstore? Does the website (before seeing anything) force you to signup too? Otherwise just make a web-app.